# Multidimensional Array to String conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a dynamic multidimensional array and I want to convert it to string.
here is an example:

```
Array
(
[data] => check
[test1] => Array
    (
        [data] => Hello
    )

[test2] => Array
    (
        [data] => world
    )

[test3] => Array
    (
        [data] => bar
        [tst] => Array
            (
                [data] => Lorem
                [bar] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => doller
                        [foo] => Array
                            (
                                [data] => sit
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[test4] => Array
    (
        [data] => HELLO
        [tst] => Array
            (
                [data] => ipsum
                [bar] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => Lorem
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

The example for string is:

```
 check&hello&world&bar...lorem&doller...sit ....
```

I have tried alot of things. I even checked the solutions given on other SO questions. like:
[Convert Multidimensional array to single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array) & [Multidimensional Array to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309047/multidimensional-array-to-string/)
But No luck.

Comment: Do you want to convert entire array in single string? Can you please add example for it.

Comment: Have you tried `$var = print_r($myArray, true);`?

Comment: @HtmHell, his given above code looks like output of print_r. How print_r($myArray) will help to convert entire array in string?

Comment: @SatishSojitra I have edited my comment.

Comment: @Uchiha This is the output of `json_decode`

Comment: @SatishSojitra I have added an example for string.

Comment: @mega6382 Thanks. I have posted answer of this question. You can add & and format your output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `array_walk_recursive` like as

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) use (&$result) {
    $result[] = $v;
});
echo implode('&', $result);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/4ZjK3)

Answer (score 1):

First convert it to flat array, by

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($input_array));
$flat = iterator_to_array($it, false);
```

`false` prevents array key collision.

Then use implode,

```
$str = implode('&', $flat);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following recursive function to convert any multidimensional array to string

```
 public function _convertToString($data,&$converted){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
                $this->_convertToString($value,$converted);

        }else{
            $converted .= '&'. $value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can call above function in following way:

```
   $str = array(
      "data" => "check",
        "test1" => array(
          "data" => "Hello",
            "test3" => array(
                "data" => "satish"
            )
        ),
        "test2" => array(
            "data" => "world"
        )
    );

    $converted = "";

    //call your function and pass your array and reference string
    $this->_convertToString($str,$converted);

    echo $converted;
```

Output will be following:

```
check&Hello&satish&world
```

you can modify code to meet your requirement.

Let me know if any further help required.

Answer (score 0):

php has some build in functions that can do this. Like var_dump, json_encode and var_export. But if you want to control the output more it can be doen with a recursive function

```
function arrToStr(array $data)
{
    $str = "";
    foreach ($data as $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $str .= arrToStr($val);
        } else {
            $str .= $val;
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

You can format extra line breaks and spaces at will with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use recursion for this type of array :

```
echo visit($your_array);

function visit($val){
    if( !is_array($val) ){
        return $val;
    }
    $out="";
    foreach($val as $v){
       $out.= "&".visit($v);
    }
    return $out;
}
```