# array to comma separated string for selected key

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

Hi I have an array just like below

```
$arr = array ( [0] => Array ( [allergy] => test ),[1] => Array ( [allergy] => test1 ) );
```

Here from that array I just want `allergy` value as comma separated string like `test,test1`

I tried implode but it's not working

```
$arr = array ( [0] => Array ( [allergy] => test ),[1] => Array ( [allergy] => test1 ) );
$str = implode (", ", $arr);
echo $str;
```

here is my [sample](https://eval.in/620438)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//array_column will work from php version 5.5,

```
$arr = array ( '0' => Array ( 'allergy' => 'test' ),'1' => Array ( 'allergy' => 'test1' ) );
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $row){
    $str .=$row['allergy'].',';
}
$str = trim($str,',');
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for that, and then use **implode()** to comma separated string.

Your code might look something like this,

```
$arr = array (array ('allergy' => 'test'),array ('allergy' => 'test1') );
$arr=array_column($arr,"allergy");
$str = implode (",", $arr);
echo $str;
```

> **array_column()** returns the values from a single column of the input,
>   identified by the second parameter(column_key).

**Demo:** https://eval.in/620454

Comment: array_column will work for php version >= 5.5

Comment: Why do you answer the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38673562/3933332 ?

Comment: @AlokPatel but it's not working in my application and my array was different.

Comment: I forgot @Rizier123, My bad. Sorry!

Comment: @LemonKazi What is not working for you?