# saving an array to a tab separated file php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that is supposed to save an array to a file that I give to it, but every array variable is supposed to be tab separated...At this point I have the function but it's not creating any file and it's not writing anything to it...Also for some reason when I try to give an array from another page, it giving me an undefined index error, even though I started a session on both page..can you help with either of the too

```
function saveorder($file,$arr){
@ $fp = fopen($file, 'w');

    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

    if (!$fp) {
      echo "<p>Your order could not be processed at this time.</p>";
    }
    else {
      fwrite($fp, _SESSION);
      flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
      fclose($fp);

      echo("<p>Order written to $file file.</p>");
    }    

}
```

Comment: You are actively suppressing errors with the '@' symbol. Never do that and ask "why doesn't this work?". It's like gagging PHP and then come asking us what's wrong, while PHP is probably trying to tell you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what is _SESSION ($_SESSION maybe?), no idea how you want to write your array but this code works for me:

```
$b = array('test' => 'result', 'another' => 'other');
saveorder('test.txt', $b);
function saveorder($file,$arr){
    @ $fp = fopen($file, 'w');

    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
    $string = '';
    foreach($arr as $key => $result)
        $string .= "$key: $result \n";

    if (!$fp) {
      echo "<p>Your order could not be processed at this time.</p>";
    }else{
      fwrite($fp, $string);
      flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
      fclose($fp);

      echo("<p>Order written to $file file.</p>");
    }    
}
```

fwrite second parameter have to be a string, so you format your array as a string however you please

EDIT:

If the array is multidimensional you can use this function as found on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309047/multidimensional-array-to-string)

```
$string = implode("&",array_map(function($a) {return implode("~",$a);},$arr));
```

Comment: What if the array is 2 dimensional associated array

Comment: The important thing is that you turn it into a string, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309047/multidimensional-array-to-string that is by far better than the approach I was going to take, gonna edit to use this.